# Delegating calls to a numpy array's method to its elements

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy array:

```
arr = np.array(["a", "b", "c"], dtype=object)
```

Now I want to perform an arbitrary function, or call an arbitrary method, on each element. For example, suppose I want to get the upper case of all these elements. "Logically" speaking, I'd like to do something like this:

```
upp_arr = arr.upper()
```

or

```
upp_arr = str.upper(arr)
```

Short version: can I accomplish either of the above?

Long version:
This is obviously not going to work, considering the array doesn't have an `upper` method (even if the individual elements do), nor does the `str` built-in know how to handle a numpy array. I don't want to build a custom version of `str.upper` that does know how to handle arrays, because that requires me to know in advance what functions the user of my array may want to use.

I could do something like

```
upp_arr = np.array([x.upper() for x in arr])
```

I don't like this, though: now I need to expose to the users of my code that `arr` is actually a numpy array. I want to get something like the above two non-working solutions.

I tried to make this happen by sub-classing `np.ndarray`, and overwriting the `__getattr__(self, name)` method to return an array of the elements' attribute of name `name` if `name` is not an attribute of `np.ndarray`, and over-writing its `__call__` method to return an array of the elements**call**` result:

```
import numpy as np

class MyArr(np.ndarray):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(np.ndarray, name):
            return getattr(np.ndarray, name)
        arr = MyArr(self.shape, dtype=object)
        arr[:] = [getattr(elem, name) for elem in self]
        return arr
    def __call__(self):
        arr = MyArr(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype)
        arr[:] = [elem() for elem in self]
        return arr

arr = MyArr((3,), dtype=object)
arr[:] = ["a", "b", "c"]
arr.upper()
```

This has two problems: constructing the array is a pain in the bum (have to instantiate it first, and then fill it with values), and I have to assume that the result of the function call is of the same dtype as the original array (the `dtype=self.dtype` part). This latter is not a problem if I stick to `object` type arrays, but will be in general.

How do solve?

Comment: I don't see the problem with construct and fill.  `numpy` does that all the time.  `vectorize` evaluates one value and uses its result to set the return dtype.  Occasionally that gives rise to SO questions.

Answer (score -1):

There is a library of functions that applies `str` operations to the elements of a string array, e.g.

```
In [199]: np.char.upper(np.array(['a','b','c']))
Out[199]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'C'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

But it does not work on arrays of dtype object:

```
In [200]: np.char.upper(np.array(['a','b','c'],dtype=object))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-200-17a9e3cc581f> in <module>()
----> 1 np.char.upper(np.array(['a','b','c'],dtype=object))
...\numpy\core\defchararray.pyc in upper(a)
   1571     """
   1572     a_arr = numpy.asarray(a)
-> 1573     return _vec_string(a_arr, a_arr.dtype, 'upper')
TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

But this `char` function isn't any faster than the corresponding list comprehension.  It still has to call the str operation on each element.  But it will be more convenient if the array is n-d.

```
In [209]: timeit np.char.upper(x1)   # large x1
1000 loops, best of 3: 277 µs per loop

In [210]: timeit np.array([i.upper() for i in x1])
1000 loops, best of 3: 278 µs per loop
```

---

A few new thoughts on the issue.

`np.frompyfunc` applies a function to all elements of an array, returning a new object dtype array.

```
In [49]: vupper = np.frompyfunc(lambda astr: astr.upper(), 1, 1)
In [50]: vupper(np.array(['a','b','c']))
Out[50]: array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)
In [51]: vupper(np.array(['a','b','c'], dtype=object))
Out[51]: array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype=object)
```

`np.vectorize` uses `np.frompyfunc`, but adds some `dtype` conversion.  In my tests `np.frompyfunc` is a bit faster; in some cases 2x faster than an equivalent list comprehension version.

Look at `numpy/core/records.py` to see how `np.recarray` lets us access structured array fields as attributes.  It wraps `__getattribute__`.

Masked arrays is a good example of an array subclass that has a large collection of custom methods.   `/numpy/ma/__init__.py`

Comment: That's still just a specific set of functions, though. I'm looking for a solution that will work with _any_ function.